# Code::Blocks получить имя текущего компилируемого файла

Tags: c++, c, отладка, codeblocks

В целях будущего поиска багов хочется иметь на выходе файл микс: ассемблер + исходники.
Нашел 3 способа:

1. Для каждого исходника перегружаем строку компиляции
   было:

`$compiler $options $includes -c $file -o $object`

стало:

`$compiler $options -Wa,-adhln=$file.lst $includes -c $file -o $object`

В принципе и так устраивает, НО это надо менять во всем проекте (а это ~100 "cpp" файлов).

2. Добавление `-save-temps` к глобальным опциям компиляции. Помимо того что выдаёт ненужные `ii` файлы, так ещё и в ассемблере нет адресов (смещения) команд.
3. Снова меняем глобальные опции компиляции. Добавляем строку вида:

`-Wa,-adhln="myfile.lst"`

Способ гораздо более предпочтительный, если бы не одно НО, как сделать чтобы `myfile` был своим для каждого файла? Перепробовал кучу встроенных вариантов вида `$(ACTIVE_EDITOR_FILENAME)` - всё не то...

Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение здесь: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Adding_support_for_non_C/C%2B%2B_files_to_the_build_system

Вкратце, надо изменить настройки компиляции не для проекта, а для Code::Blocks в целом.